# How to deny the Client to unbind the RMI Registry?

Tags: java, rmi, rmiregistry

I write a simple RMI application. I found out that the Client after getting the RMI-Registry can execute successful the Registry.unbind() method. This is in my opinion a security risk. Why it is allowed to the Client to unbind the Name in the remote Registry? A evil person can do this with a modification of the Code and all my other Clients cann't connect to my Server because the binding was removed.

Is there a possibility to deny this, maybe in the Java policy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can only happen if the client is running in the same host as the Registry. If you are having security problems wth your own clients, you have a much bigger problem than anything RMI can solve for you.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/rmi/registry/Registry.html) for Registry:

> A Registry implementation may choose to restrict access to some or all
>   of its methods (for example, methods that mutate the registry's
>   bindings may be restricted to calls originating from the local host).
>   If a Registry method chooses to deny access for a given invocation,
>   its implementation may throw AccessException, which (because it
>   extends RemoteException) will be wrapped in a ServerException when
>   caught by a remote client.

You have the option of preventing this behavior if you so choose (its actually the default behavior for most registry implementations).